# Obtain a drawable with getResources().getIdentifier() in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, drawable

I would like to programmatically adjust the background of several buttons in a button array. In doing so, I would like to assemble the identifier from a string and a number.

In the case of a text resource in `strings.xml`, I have already been able to put this together functionally:

```
basicDEGR[g].setVoc(getResources().getIdentifier("vocGR" + (g +((category-1)*20)), "string", getPackageName()));
```

Unfortunately, a similar approach with drawables does not work:

```
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        Button button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        Button button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        Button button10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);

        Button[] button = new Button[] {button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10};

        for (int i = 1; i<11; i++) 
        {
          button[i].setBackground(getResources().getIdentifier("gr" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
        }
```

Currently i am getting this kind of error:

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Drawable
                button[i].setBackground(getResources().getIdentifier("gr" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
                                                                ^
```

What would be a correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use `setBackgroundResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View#setbackgroundresource) to set a background using a drawable (or color) resource given the resource ID.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much, works like a charm :-)  ///     


for (int i = 1; i<6; i++) {
                button[i-1].setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier("gr"+i, "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
            }